# activate bluetooth on WIN CE

Tags: bluetooth, registry, windows-ce

on my version of WIN CE there is a program installed called **"Wireless Config Control Panel"**
which activates or DeActivates Bluetooth and WiFi.
I want **Bluetooth** active on start up.
Where can i manually **active** Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a function to enable/disable the Bluetooth radio:

```
int BthSetMode(DWORD dwMode);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916815.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply! To use this I need Bthutil.lib but it seems it's not available on Win CE. I've tried _BluetoothRadio br = BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio; br.Mode = RadioMode.Connectable;_ but this didn't worked. any other ideas?

Comment: I called it from C++ in my app; not sure about C#.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

- [SetDevicePower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee497782.aspx)
- [BthSetMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee495834.aspx) (BthUtil)
- ChangeRadioState (OSSVCS)

There is a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103104/Radio-Power) with examples.

Comment: Thanks! But these examples are all for C++, I should have stated I need this to work with c#. how can I use this in c#? Thanks - Martijn

Comment: There is no BCL method for doing these things in the .NET CF. You will need to p/invoke those methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old question. Adding answer for anyone who is searching for.

There is one way to do this by modifying registry. (You can do this from application too)

In registry, do the below modifications:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Bluetooth\sys]
   "Power"=dword:1                  ; Radio on by default
   "ScanMode"=dword:3               ; Radio is discoverable
   "DisableAutoSuspend"=dword:1     ; Allow suspend when connected
```

Here, You should write 1 to Power to switch BT ON, and ScanMode to 3 to make it discoverable if you want so.

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Bluetooth\sys]
>
> "Power"=dword:**1**                  ; Radio on by default
>
> "ScanMode"=dword:**3**               ; Radio is discoverable
>
> "DisableAutoSuspend"=dword:1     ; Allow suspend when connected